# Magento V1.9 is running in timeout after sales_flat_quote_item update in event observer

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, observers

I try to save additional information (from third-party-system) to `sales_flat_quote_item` db in Magento V1.9.
The observer works fine.

The data which should be updated, were updated, but everytime it ends in an "Internal Server Error 500", even if I add a `die()` after the `$quoteItem->save();`

There is no timeout when I comment `$quoteItem->save();` out <- But then nothing was saved

config.xml

```
<events>
    <sales_quote_item_save_commit_after>
        <observers>
            <MyCompany_MyProject_salesQuoteItemSaveCommitAfter>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>MyCompany_MyProject_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>salesQuoteItemSaveCommitAfter</method>
            </MyCompany_MyProject_salesQuoteItemSaveCommitAfter>
        </observers>
    </sales_quote_item_save_commit_after>
</events>
```

Observer.php

```
/**
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     */
    public function salesQuoteItemSaveCommitAfter($observer)
    {
        //var_dump($post); die();

        $quoteItem = $observer->getEvent()->getItem();
        //var_dump($quoteItem->getId()); echo die();

        if (!$quoteItem->getId()) {
            //quote not saved in the database
            return $this;
        }
        //var_dump($quoteItem->getId()); die();

        $quoteItem->setPriceInclTax($post['my_custom_price']);
        $quoteItem->save();
        
        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: I think I know why it comes to a timeout.
I think in case of the event observer it comes into a enless loop, because of changes on quote items and recall the event again & again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes exactly,
The event sales_quote_item_save_commit_after  is launched after each recording of the quote entity, here in the code when the $quoteItem->save();  is launched, just after the observer is restarted and so on : which creates an infinite loop.
In this case you can instead use the sales_quote_item_save_before event or perform a check to verify that the PriceInclTax field has been recorded.